# validating webhook configuration not getting any request

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have defined a `validatingWebhook` configuration with a custom controller that is deployed as a deployment, snippet below for `validatingWebhook`:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: validate-webhook
  namespace: admission-test
webhooks:
  - name: admission.validate.com
   namespaceSelector:
  matchExpressions:
    - key: app
      operator: NotIn
      values: ["admission-test"]
rules:
  - apiGroups:   ["*"]
    apiVersions: ["v1","v1beta1","v1alpha1"]
    operations:  ["CREATE","UPDATE"]
    resources:   ["deployments","daemonsets","statefulsets","cronjobs", "rollouts", "jobs"]
    scope:       "Namespaced"
clientConfig:
  service:
    namespace: admission-test
    name: admission-test
    #service port
    port: 8090
    path: /verify
admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
sideEffects: None
```

and on my application I have defined a `http Handler`, snippet is below:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/verify", servePod)
http.HandleFunc("/healthz", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(200)
    klog.Infoln("hittinh healthz")
    w.Write([]byte("ok"))
})
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:      fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port),
    TLSConfig: admission.ConfigTLS(config),
}
```

I am trying to create another simple nginx deployment, which can be found [here](https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml) but when I try to print the the body of `/verify` in customer controller that I wrote, I don't get anything. In fact it's like the other deployments are not passing through the admission controller.

Any pointers on why this is happening? Much appreciated

running kubernetes version

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.4", GitCommit:"3cce4a82b44f032d0cd1a1790e6d2f5a55d20aae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-11T18:16:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.4", GitCommit:"3cce4a82b44f032d0cd1a1790e6d2f5a55d20aae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-11T18:10:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

k8s cluster is running via docker desktop

Comment: could you please explain what does this mean "print the the body of /verify"? Kindly ask you to provide the commands you do and what you want to get. Look at the logs, it should be some. And please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Comment: @Bazhikov so the validationwebhook sends a post request to my $svc/verify (the http endpoint i exposed in my custom controller), but when i deploy the nginx deployment, the deployment goes without passing through the vaidation controller

Answer (score 1):

It's passing through the validation controller due to it's set as `scope:       "Namespaced"` and I can't see any `namespace` specified in your nginx deployment file. You can add any working `namespace` or change your `scope` to `"*"`

You can find more information about the rules in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#matching-requests-rules)

Comment: i've changed the namespace to whatever namespace i've given in the admission controller

Comment: @sai, and? has it worked?